# TFS Configuration

Tags: sql-server, tfsbuild

I am trying to restore data from a series of databases onto a new server. The steps I have taken so far are:

- Copy backup files (and transaction logs) to new server
- Restore each database using SQL Server 2012
- Attempt to run the Application Tier Only configuration tool in TFS 2015 (same version as the "LIVE" server.

When the wizard runs I get through the initial checks and the when it attempts to start the configuration I get the below error.

Can anyone suggest what the problem may be (I have tried remapdb but keep getting the syntax wrong)?

Error Text:

> TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: TF246083: The configuration of Team Foundation Server is not valid. You must remap the databases in order to fix the configuration. The following error was received from the server: TF400673: Unable to find any compatible SQL Analysis Services database within the specified instance.
>   '2' hosts have been given updated connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to Clone a server. Please make sure you exactly following the instruction : [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-clone-hardware) or [Restore data to a different server than the current one for TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance)

Anyway, you can refer below info to fix the issue quickly: 
According to the error message, seems you have not restored the `TFS_Analysis` database.

(More information please see Chaminda's Blog - [Prepare Restored Databases](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/08/cloning-your-tfs-server-part-02-prepare.html))

1. Restore the `TFS_Analysis` database first. (If that restored, just
   try to remove it, then restore it again)
2. Then run the PrepareClone command to check if there are any errors. (You must run this command before
   configuring AT of your cloned TFS)

   `TFSConfig PrepareClone /SQLInstance:ServerName /DatabaseName:TFSConfigurationDatabaseName /notificationURL:ApplicationTierURL`
3. After prepare clone, execute the [ChangeServerID](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#changeserverid) command to change the
   server GUIDs associated with the TFS databases.

   `TFSConfig ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:ServerName /DatabaseName:ConfigurationDatabaseName`
4. After that, execute [RemapDBs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs) command to redirect TFS to its databases in new hardware.

   `TFSConfig RemapDBs /DatabaseName:ServerName;ConfigurationDatabaseName /SQLInstances:ServerName1,ServerName2 [/AnalysisInstance:ServerName] [/AnalysisDatabaseName:DatabaseName] [/preview] [/continue] [/usesqlalwayson]`