# TFS Installation error at Configure section of Application Tier Only Wizard

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

When doing Application Tier only installation on TFS, I received the following error at the Configure section of the Application Tier Only Wizard.

TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: TF246083: The configuration of Team Foundation Server is not valid. You must remap the databases in order to fix the configuration. The following error was received from the server: TF400673: Unable to find any compatible SQL Analysis Services database within the specified instance.
'2' hosts have been given updated connection strings.
.. For more information, see the configuration log.

How do I resolve this error?

[Image Link for Application Tier Only Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc2AP.png)

Comment: Have you ever moved or cloned the TFS deployment or restored the TFS DBs?

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to anothe](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware#clone)r.

Based on the error message, seems you have not restored the **TFS_Analysis** database or somthing wrong with the restored TFS_Analysis database.

So, you can try to restore the **TFS_Analysis** database, then check it again. If the issue still exists there, then you can refer to below thread and following the steps to fix that:

- [TFS Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113904/tfs-configuration)
- [Cloning Your TFS Server Part 02 – Prepare Restored Databases](http://chamindac.blogspot.sg/2017/08/cloning-your-tfs-server-part-02-prepare.html)

---

**UPDATE:**

You have to restore the `TFS_Analysis` database first, you can not configure the AT without the DB. Alternatively you can do a complete new installation and create a new TFS deployment. See [Install TFS on a single server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/install/single-server) for details.

Comment: Yes, the TFS_Analysis service database is NOT restored. For now, I don't have a copy of that instance. So, I tried creating a dummy instance and tried installing the application tier. But, it still fails. Moreover, as stated in "TFS Configuration" article, I have tried remapdb but I keep getting the syntax wrong.                                               & '.\TfsConfig.exe' remapdbs  /SQLInstances:Tfs_Configuration /DatabaseName:serverName/Tfs_Configuration /Continue                                                                   Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Varun No, you have to restore the TFS_Analysis database first, you can not configure the AT without the DB. Alternatively you can do a complete new installation and create  a new TFS deployment. See [Install TFS on a single server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/install/single-server) for details.

Comment: Hi Andy...unfortunately we dropped this approach and followed a fresh installation instead.